# Why are we able to observe seemingly "inertial objects" in our day to day life? (apparent paradox from Newton's second law)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, everyday-life, approximations

On the table and near to the computer where I write this question on, is my phone, and in my observation, it is completely still. Now, by Newton´s first law, since it is inertial, there is no net external force.

But, I know for sure that´s not true. The earth moves around the sun, and by extension, my phone does as well. So, clearly the body is not at rest when we start considering more and more of the universe. But, to our eye it is completly at rest.

So is this a paradox or am I missing something?

Comment: What do you mean there is no external forces?! Shouldn't it be more like: The sum of external forces cancel? Anyway, the point is that you also move around the sun and so on, just like your phone --and hence you don't observe that you and your phone diverge with time. It is the same as being in a train. Everything around you is at rest (if everyone sits lol), but you, the train and everything in it is moving (relative to the ground). Would you call this a paradox?

Comment: Objects are not "inertial", instead you have "inertial frames".  Also, you must be more careful with the language around velocity and acceleration: "at rest" and "in motion" (with constant velocity vector) are exactly the same situation. It is the circular motion (of the Earth about the Sun, or the surface of the Earth about its axis) that implies *acceleration* which makes a frame on Earth non-inertial.

Comment: I had meant that only @TobiasFünke.

Answer (score 6):

> On the table and near to the computer where I write this question on,
> is my phone, and in my observation, it is completely still.

From your observation you can only conclude that your cell phone is not moving *relative to you, your computer, and the table.* If you were to look at the stars on a clear night long enough you will see that you (your phone, computer, and table) are moving relative to the stars.

> Now, by Newton´s first law, since it is inertial, there is no net
> external force.

In addition to being at rest, to be inertial if you’re moving you need to be moving in a straight line at constant speed. But you already know that not to be the case as you are undergoing circular motion (The net force being the centripetal force of gravity.)

> So, clearly the body is not at rest when we start considering more and
> more of the universe. But, to our eye it is completely at rest. So is
> this a paradox or am I missing something?

Your observance of the stars would tell you it is not completely at rest. Although your phone undergoes circular motion along with the surface of the Earth due to gravity, the curvature is so small locally it can be considered moving in a straight line at constant speed, locally approximating an inertial frame, at least for brief periods of time. The only thing you were missing is the fact that the body is not at rest relative to a reference frame other than yours.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Newton's First Law should be thought of like this:

> An *inertial frame* is one for which an object experiencing zero net force moves with a constant velocity. Newton's laws should only be applied in an inertial frame.

It is a definition of an inertial frame and a statement that the other laws of motion should only be used in an inertial frame.  But it is also a *test* of whether you are in an inertial frame: place an object on the ground; it appears that it has zero net force (gravity down, normal up); but if you see it jump to the side without a force to explain its acceleration, then you are not in an inertial frame (maybe you are in the back of a truck).

So, for your situation, the behavior of your phone (and other, potentially more precarious, objects in your room) *demonstrates* that your room is an inertial frame.  Therefore you can expect to get good results when using, e.g., Newton's Second Law.

Of course, you are right that your room is *not* an inertial frame. The Earth is "moving" around the Sun but more importantly it is *accelerating* in its circular motion. Also the rotation of the Earth about its axis means that you and your room and your phone are accelerating in circular motion about that axis.

But this test of an inertial frame, I guess, should be thought of as an experimental observation.  Up to some limits of your experimental tools, your room is an inertial frame, and therefore, up to some error, it is an adequate laboratory for predicting the outcome of experiments with Newton's Second Law.

[Of course, we are assuming a Newtonian universe here, in which Gravity is a force ...]

Answer (score 2):

No paradox, just measurement errors. Our senses are wonderful, but when it comes to precision, many of the effects you describe fit in the noise.  They're there, but we just lack the ability to measure it.  At least we do with the human body.  We can construct devices which can measure these non-inertial effects.  The simplest would probably be the [Foucault Pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum), a pendulum devised in 1851 to demonstrate that the earth is rotating (non-inertial).

With a little math, we can compute the effect of these effects.  You mention the effects of the Earth whizzing around the sun, so let's calculate that.  The Earth moves at 29.78km/s.  Yes, that's kilometers per second.  And the Earth is 149,600,000km away from the sun (that's an average number, sometimes we're nearer or closer).  We can compute the non-inertial acceleration due to that rotation using $a=\frac{v^2}{r}$, which puts our acceleration at $0.006\frac m s^2$  It is very hard to detect an acceleration on that scale.  You chose a phone as an example object, so lets put numbers to that.  An iPhone 15 is 171g.  A mass of 171g experienceing an acceleration of $0.006\frac m s^2$ corresponds with a force of 0.001N.

A force like that would fit well into the uncertainty of our force measurements, so we would feel like a frame was inertial, even though it technically is non-inertial.  Air currents around the phone would generate larger forces.

All models are wrong, some are useful.  It can be useful to do calculations and make predictions with the assumption that our on-the-ground frame is inertial.  In many situations, that is close enough.  Other times, it is insufficient.  When in doubt, you can do calculations like I did to determine whether a particular non-inertial effect will be detectable by a particular laboratory setup.

Answer (score 0):

One way to model it:

You are connected to the table by solid matter. Electromagnetic and Pauli forces in the matter constrain you and the objects on the table to follow parallel trajectories. Constraining forces work this way: they adjust themselves to geometric necessity.

Answer (score 0):

The phone is 'on the table' only because you recognize up/down direction of local gravity force. That means there is external force.

Comment: you  can´t be serious

Comment: Every infant learns the force of gravity; of course I'm serious.  The up/down circumstance  of a phone atop a table is a reminder of that force.